# Installing sculpting brushes permanently

Tags: installation

I wonder if there is a way to install brushes (sculpting ones) to be accessible all the time when I open Blender. I know I could APPEND these and use them but everytime I close Blender and then start it up again I have to repeat the process.

Found out that I should be able to append them and save the Startup File but it does NOT work for me. Any ideas?

Sincerely, Jan

Comment: It's simple, just start a new project, add the brushes, and after you press ctrl+u

Comment: If You just try to read again the question, then You will find out that it does NOT work for me.

Comment: Better - check *Fake User* option when appending brushes

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to set fake user for all appended brushes and then "Save Startup File".

Comment: Awesome! Worked perfectly!

Comment: it's not clear to me what's the meaning of "set fake user".

Comment: it works for me. I have to check this fake user icon for every brush.

Answer (score 0):

To answer to [Sanbaldo](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/88382/sanbaldo) in the previous post

[image]

Hope it can help